# Is length of rowid in Oracle 11g fixed?

Tags: c, database, oracle, oracle11g, proc

Is it possible to configure Oracle 11g installation so that it has more than 18 characters length?

Investigating possible cause of locally un-producible bug that might have been caused if customer configured rowid to have more than 18 characters.

The table doesn't have an index. Using rowid to delete given records shortly after, but it's possible that other records are inserted in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really looking at a l[ogical `ROWID` (`UROWID`) or a `ROWID` from a non-Oracle database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i6732), sure.  If you're trying to store a `ROWID`, you should really be using a `UROWID` data type rather than `ROWID` and you shouldn't be persisting that storage since the `ROWID` of a row can change over time and a `ROWID` can refer to different rows over time.

If I create an index-organized table

```
SQL> create table bar ( col1 varchar(1000) primary key, col2 number ) organization index;

Table created.
```

then add a row and look at the `ROWID`, you'll see that the string representation is much longer than 18 characters

```
  1* insert into bar select lpad( 'x', 1000, 'y' ), 1 from dual
SQL> /

1 row created.

SQL> select rowid from bar
  2  ;

ROWID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*BAEG2COD6Hl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl

ROWID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXj+
```

If I try to `SELECT` the `ROWID` into a `UROWID` variable, my anonymous block succeeds.  If I do the same thing into a `ROWID` variable, it fails

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_rowid urowid;
  3  begin
  4    select rowid
  5      into l_rowid
  6      from bar;
  7    dbms_output.put_line( l_rowid );
  8  end;
  9  /
*BAEG2COD6Hl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl
5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXj+

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2    l_rowid rowid;
  3  begin
  4    select rowid
  5      into l_rowid
  6      from bar;
  7    dbms_output.put_line( l_rowid );
  8* end;
SQL> /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I can retrieve it from Pro*C code I use. I read it into a char[]

Comment: @sny - Presumably, you could read the string representation into a much larger character array.  I'm not sure whether Pro*C has a proper `UROWID` data type.

Comment: the table doesn't have primary key or index though. It seems like rowid getting bigger to acomodate big primary key.

Comment: How else can I identify and delete particular row, considering other rows might be added in between (given that I enlarged the buffer to be larger than rowid)?